# Trigonometry problem with complementary angles

Tags: trigonometry

$\tan(n.90 + (-1)^{n }.45)$

Find the integral value of the above expression

My try

I wrote it as ${\sin\over \cos}$

Then I used casework

ie. $n = 2k+1$ or $2k$

But my case work leads to the answer of $\pm 1$

However the answer is only $+1$

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You should find that the angle is always $45^o$ plus a multiple of $360^o$ or $225^o$ plus a multiple of $360^o$, so the tangent is always 1.

Comment: Cases is good. Before dealing with general $n$, it is useful to compute for particular $n$. If $n=1$, we are looking at $\tan(45^\circ)$, which is $1$. If $n=2$, we are looking at $\tan(225^\circ)$, which is $1$. For $n=3$ we are again looking at $\tan(225^\circ)$.